# How to refer to MEDIA_URL from settings.py in models.py?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-settings, django-media

I know that it is maybe not the most beautiful thing to partialy deling with view in model, but for now I would like to solve my problem this way.

in my models.py for one class I define:

```
def admin_image(self):
    return '<img src="/media/%s"/>' % self.thumbnail.photo
admin_image.allow_tags = True
```

**BUT I would like that instead of hard coded /media/ there MEDIA_URL will be used, but have no idea how to call it. I am newbie to django, so please be kind :)**

in my settings.py I defined:

```
PROJECT_ROOT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT_PATH, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and in admin.py I use `readonly_fields = ['admin_image']` and then I use it in list_display and fieldsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I think I got it. Anyway comments how to deal with it better will be apriciated.

in models.py:

```
from django.conf import settings

def admin_image(self):
    return '<img src="'+settings.MEDIA_URL+'%s"/>' % self.thumbnail.photo
admin_image.allow_tags = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Append the media prefix only in the view. See how to do that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#get-media-prefix

And refer to the obj.thumbnail.photo just in the template.